# Invalid Redirect Uri error while accessing Access Management, After upgraded Access Management 2.0

Tags: sites-9.5, access-management

When we are upgrading Access Management to 2.0 as per below Article
https://docs.rws.com/1099765/949800/tridion-sites-10-main-documentation/upgrading-------------access-management
I followed all the Steps

1. DB Upgrade complete
2. Created a backup of the current Access management service folder.
3. Uninstalled the service
4. Configure new appsettings.json with existing properties.
5. Installed the service
6. Service Installed Successfully
7. When Trying to browse Access Management URL it says |Invalid redirect_uri.
8. Attached Logs, Please let me know if you can connect with us and help us in Troubleshooting

> 2023-11-07 08:15:20.8298|Error|Duende.IdentityServer.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator|Invalid redirect_uri: "https://tridion-dev.xy.net:8443/access-management/signin-oidc"
> {"ClientId":"Access_Management", "ClientName":"Access Management", "AllowedRedirectUris":["http://localhost:5000/access-management/ui/signin-oidc","https://tridion-dev.xy.net:8443/access-management/ui/signin-oidc","https://localhost:8443/access-management/ui/signin-oidc","https://YOURTAMHOSTNAME:84/access-management/signin-oidc"], "SubjectId":"anonymous", "RequestedScopes":"", "PromptMode":"", "Raw":{"client_id":"Access_Management","redirect_uri":"https://tridion-dev.xy.net:8443/access-management/signin-oidc","response_type":"code","scope":"openid profile role forwarded offline_access","code_challenge":"Z8TtGPRmLmiGxU9zXkVTgnkRPX3_z0iyuqQz2LlEqIU","code_challenge_method":"S256","nonce":"638349381208108289.ZmVkMjBjOGUtODdhZS00NTMxLTkwOWMtNGQyODBmODI5MDVjODBiNWVhYTYtYjY4ZC00NTg0LWEyOTYtOTI5NjRmMDNiMzJj","state":"CfDJ8IIyr9OXhB9Iphs15S9DlbBy9sA_GmtDYzVp6b5I7K8_2oOUl36q2_I9YIF4e4GU2qODCpU-lUcOhUOgxP-K7XbI53bYlkNJXdYKf15fpuE_jpxggCvPKySYbn2lB04giitetcMEOfPtQcShbKISHBZLvhcKykUeM4BSV6bdhFxfwWNLHB3OejzxHh39awzAiL1KtwY9giyQgEtM_012NAz79EZPVa0i01WXn81fKrkk0P6KlU7QdDPzxDMtFUkgCc4fnCyDYRPBfbyUFrZCSMww6n73MNn3p_nB-WKOh0jnXjazoQPNBksnT3Ph_kWtYRS9r8aOs7F7-yHRDyYStTYAVoJ9oHHWrb_G7Q1VtPEmCvf2dFQPyRff656WvmM5RUJrCE1o7laxXrroGKIs-WbRiBG4Vg94amzc9sofeaRXRq401T8Q60TnTOvak9ZaPg","x-client-SKU":"ID_NETSTANDARD2_0","x-client-ver":"6.10.0.0"}}

Can you please help me to Troubleshoot, If I rollback changes its working fine.

after Stefan suggestion fixed the issue.

Now getting below error

> "2023-11-10 10:28:13.6052|Error|Duende.IdentityServer.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator|Invalid grant type for client: "implicit"
> {"ClientId":"Classic_Tridion_Sites_UI", "ClientName":"Tridion Sites Classic (UI only)", "RedirectUri":"https://tridion-dev.xy.net/webui/signin-oidc", "AllowedRedirectUris":["https://tridion-dev.xy.net:443/webui/signin-oidc","https://tridion-dev.xy.net/webui/signin-oidc","https://tridion-dev.xy.net:443/ui/signin-oidc","https://YOURCMHOSTNAME:81/webui/signin-oidc"], "SubjectId":"anonymous", "ResponseType":"id_token token", "ResponseMode":"form_post", "GrantType":"implicit", "RequestedScopes":"", "State":"OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=Bizgx-TwNQ4jf4tKB_pVr5h8-Aj3SqygLEVEoJJj2Yv-GTnwG6_NnWdpY2txDUVEQnwQ2B-DeOr_ltFD5hI", "PromptMode":"", "Raw":{"client_id":"Classic_Tridion_Sites_UI","response_type":"id_token token","scope":"openid profile role forwarded","state":"OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=Bizgx-0uSarRzX7MJmz8Hl4tKB_pV0h8-AEoJJj2Yv-p3MgojdFRFCURgl_BMTUuIEeNnWdp-DeOr_ltFD5hI","response_mode":"form_post","nonce":"63835205202.lNzEtTkxODItODUxZDVmZDM4Y2Q3","redirect_uri":"https://tridion-dev.xy .net/webui/signin-oidc","x-client-SKU":"ID_NET461","x-client-ver":"5.3.0.0"}}
> 2023-11-10 10:28:13.6104|Error|Duende.IdentityServer.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint|Request validation failed "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log indicates that your configured [AllowedRedirectUris] doesn't contain new redirect URL that you are trying to open.

Your new URL https://tridion-dev.xy.net:8443/access-management/signin-oidc
In allowed redirect Uris list there is similar URL (but not the same) https://tridion-dev.xy.net:8443/access-management/ui/signin-oidc (note the /ui/ part).

You could either add new redirect URL on old Access Management and then perform upgrade again or if you already have upgraded Access Management you can temporarily disable security on it and add new redirect URL or you can add new URL directly to the database (I would use this approach as last resort).

Comment: Thank you Stefan, I used last approach as I used similar approach last time. It worked, Now when I try to access Tridion I am getting above error

Comment: Please verify that in your identity server (Duende) you configured redirect url properly. From log message It seems that you have space before .net in your configured url
https://tridion-dev.xy[SPACE].net/webui/signin-oidc

Comment: Invalid grant type for client: "implicit" error occurred as "allowed authentication flow type" field configured in Applications tab as "AuthorizationCodeWithPkce"., once changed to implicit issue resolved.